# User-friendly Jenkins CI job schedule format

Tags: c#, mysql, amazon-web-services, jenkins, cron

I'm considering using Jenkins CI basically as a job scheduler.  I'm planning to let the end users create, update and delete jobs.  The main hurdle I can see is that job schedules are specified in cron syntax which is perfectly un-user-friendly.

Anyone know of any user-friendly scheduling plugins out there?  Something like the windows event scheduler (see below) would do.

Alternatively, are there any other (Windows) scheduling solutions out there that I should be looking at?  I looked at a bunch and Jenkins seemed overall the best for our needs:

- half-decent web-based UI out of the box (preferably skinnable)
- small number of users
- small number of jobs
- flexible
- relatively lightweight, low-overhead
- has a Web API for programmatic access

For the record we're a Windows / AWS / C# / MySql / JS shop. With some Java. Linux isn't an immediate no-no either.

Thanks in advance,
Pete

[image: windows event scheduler]

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins is designed for build management and continuous integration. I think it's too much if you will only use it for job scheduling.

You can try other job scheduling and automation solution like Rundeck.

http://rundeck.org/news/2014/01/08/Jenkins-is-for-development-Rundeck-is-for-operations.html

Comment: Thanks @jinggoy I'm having a look now. It has a lot of support for multi-node execution (which we don't really need) but crucially it does have a (too) simple scheduling form.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Windows Scheduler to schedule one-time runs of Jenkins jobs. You will need to execute Jenkins CLI commands for that

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+CLI

Comment: Not a bad idea except for that I want to keep the users in one app, rather than switching between several.  Also, I like the way in Jenkins that you can build drop-downs and other predefined parameters. I don't think Task Scheduler does that.

Comment: Have the Jenkins job present dropdowns: day, month, time, etc. Accept these parameters from user, and schedule the job execution through Windows Scheduler using the `at` command. This way it uses Jenkins to "collect" the scheduling criteria, but does the scheduling through Windows Scheduler. And then again, the actual execution will take place in Jenkins.

Comment: Nice. However if you look at the Task Scheduler screenshot above there's a lot more going on than just DD MM YY, including logic that en/disables controls accordingly - way beyond Jenkins' parameter-building capabilities.